# How can i get the sum of three char numbers?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T Summation(T a, T b, T c) {
  return (a+b+c);
}

int main () {
  char e = '5', f = '6', g = '7', h;
  int a = 5, b = 6, c = 7, d; 

  h=Summation<char>(e,f,g);
  cout << h << endl;
  d=Summation<char>(a,b,c);
  cout << d << endl;
}
```

I must use a Template for Summation and i need to print out 18 of the same type as the arguments. So the program should return 18 as a char type then the next line should return 18 as type int.

Comment: yes, sorry it was a mistake but i corrected it

Comment: If `h == 18`, then `cout << h` will probably print only whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the general template for most types, and add a specialization for char:

```
template <class T>
T Summation(T a, T b, T c) {
  return (a+b+c);
}

template <>
char Summation<char>(char a, char b, char c) {
  return ((a - '0') + (b - '0') + (c - '0') );
}
```

Usage (just as you had in the example, just the type is inferred by the compiler):

```
 char e = '5', f = '6', g = '7', h;
  int a = 5, b = 6, c = 7, d; 

  h= Summation(e,f,g);
  d= Summation(a,b,c);
```

Comment: This would work but for some reason it wont return anything as a char even when a=b=c=1

Comment: @user1082764 You need to either pass arguments that are variables of type char, cast the arguments to char, or invoke the char type explicitly: Summation<char>(1,1,1);

Comment: The compiler must infer that the arguments are of type char for the right specialization to be called

Comment: @user1082764 Added an example of how it should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to not use templates at all and just do:

```
    int Summation(int a, int b, int c)
    {
      return a + b + c;
    }

    int Summation(char a, char b, char c)
    {
      return a - '0' + b - '0' + c - '0';
    }
```

But if you must use templates:

```
    template <class T>
    int Summation(T a, T b, T c)
    {
      T offset = std::is_same<T, char>::value ? '0' : 0;
      return a - offset + b - offset + c - offset;
    }
```

Note that you can't return 18 as a char in the sense of having a char '18' (actually that's a multi-character literal, but they are not portable) so the function returns an `int` regardless of the type `T` in my example above.

**EDIT**:

The way to call it is like this:

```
    char e = '5', f = '6', g = '7';
    int a = 5, b = 6, c = 7;
    cout << Summation(a,b,c) << endl;
    cout << Summation(e,f,g) << endl;
```

Don't specify the type to use (ie, don't do `Summation<char>(...)`), the compiler can figure it out itself and should be the one to do so whenever possible.
If you store the result type in a `char` and print it out with `cout` it will print a `char` and `(char)18` is not an ascii character and what you get depends on you console.  Make sure the type is an `int` when you print it and you will get `18` in both cases.

Comment: The second solution returns nothing when a, b, and c are char but it works fine with int

Answer (score -2):

It's not clear if you need template metaprogramming or what, a simple solution would be something like:

```
template <char A, char B, char C>
int char_sum()
{
  return (A-'0')+(B-'0')+(C-'0');
}

std::cout << "sum is " << char_sum<'5','6','7'>() << std::endl;
```

Mind that, if I remember correctly, it is safe to assume that digits are encoded in successive values (so `A-'0'` is a safe operation) as imposed by ISO standard.